# Help with new install of small bathroom in basement?

Tags: bathroom, drain, drain-waste-vent

I'm installing a brand new bathroom in my basement! I'm a DIYer, so after lots of learning, I'm looking for some experienced advice with the layout. I've only done remodels, not new installs.
I'm thinking a pocket door will be necessary to save space, and maybe even making it a wet bath? Not sure if a pocket door would work in a wet bath though.
Constraints:

1. It's a very small space. Any wider, and the hallway becomes too small (less than 36"). Any longer and I have HVAC in the way (see below)
2. There's an 8" duct overhead that can't be raised (perpendicular to floor joints). I was thinking I'd put half of it in the wall and box the other half in the shower. Thoughts?
3. The wall on the top of the image is concrete foundation, not ferred out. It's just glued-on drywall. Ferring out to have plumbing/electrical in that wall will reduce the width, so I figured I'd go underground.
4. The 4" main drain is nearby (space behind toilet), but very shallow. Only about 2.5" deep. So putting the toilet further away might be an issue.
5. I'd like to fit a toilet, sink, shower, and stackable washer/dryer outside, if at all possible.

I don't really understand venting, so let me know if you see anything wrong here. I think it's set up properly for wet venting by the washer/dryer. I also attached a picture of the current space, to give an idea of what I'm seeing/thinking (the washer/dryer hookup in the picture is not tied into the main drain anymore).[image]

Comment: Your picture failed to attach

Comment: Beyond some mechanics/code review (is there enough room around your toilet, do you have GFCI outlets/breakers for the bathroom, are lights/outlets on different breakers), there's not much we can offer that wouldn't be somebody's opinion. If you'll take the [tour] and read through the [help] you'll see that opinion-based questions are off-topic because we can't offer you a "best" or code-compliant answer to an opinion.

Comment: Thank you. I've attached the image for review.